# Material Vertical Divider isn't showing up

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I made a really simple program because i wanted to try out the vertical divider provided by angular material but for some reason it's not showing up.
My code is:

```
<div>
  <span>code</span>
</div>
<mat-divider [vertical]="true"></mat-divider>
<div>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add theming file to your `styles.css`?

Comment: Did you add Angular Material to your project? Is any error message displayed? Also, you should remove the brackets from vertical: `vertical="true"`

Comment: Did you define MatDividerModule inside app.module.ts?

Comment: I had to add it to the module list and set the height to make it visible

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try adding a height to the vertical divider.

```
<mat-divider vertical style="height:100px"></mat-divider>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wp9f4j?embed=1&file=app/divider-overview-example.html

Comment: what if i whant to set it
`<mat-divider vertical style="height:100%"></mat-divider>`

Comment: height:100% isnt working for me, Could you tell use @Marshal ?

Comment: I think it's not working anymore

Comment: mat-divider is auto adjusting to this container height
<div style="height: 200px; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 50px 10px 50px;">
 text
 <mat-divider [vertical]="true"></mat-divider>
 test
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following class to .css

```
.mat-divider-vertical{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px !important;
  position: inherit !important;
}
```

and set
style="position: relative;"
to outer element to make "100%" work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below approach to get mat-divider vertical to work for my code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 px-2">Search</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="search" class="form-control " placeholder="Search" name="search">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 px-2">Search</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="search" class="form-control " placeholder="Search" name="search">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 px-2">Search</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="search" class="form-control " placeholder="Search" name="search">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<mat-divider [vertical]="true" style="height: auto;"></mat-divider>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 px-2">Search</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="search" class="form-control " placeholder="Search" name="search">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Along with

```
.mat-divider-vertical{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px !important;
  position: inherit !important;
}
```

[screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh01G.png)